# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} \frac{5^i - 2^{3i+1}}{7^{i-2}+8^i}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble finding the answer to the limit 
$$\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} \dfrac{5^i - 2^{3i+1}}{7^{i-2}+8^i}$$

---

I get the answer 98, which to me seem to be wrong. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not 2? It looks like 2

Comment: @Dr.MV wouldn't be -2?

Comment: @Ironping, sorry my bad. i was harping on 2(2^3i)/8^i

Comment: @SakethMalyala no problem thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Ironping Yes, it is $-2$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Note first that $2^{3i+1}=2(8^i)$

Finish by dividing numerator and denominator by $8^i$ and letting $i \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

In
$a_i 
= \frac{5^i - 2^{3i+1}}{7^{i-2}+8^i}
$,
note that
$2^{3i+1}
=2^{3i}2
=2\cdot 8^i
$.

Therefore
$a_i 
= \frac{5^i - 2\cdot 8^i}{7^{i}/49+8^i}
= \frac{(5/8)^i - 2}{(7/8)^{i}/49+1}
\to -2
$
since
$(5/8)^i \to 0$
and
$(7/8)^i \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone 
got it 
$a_i = \frac{5^i - 2^{3i+1}}{7^{i-2}+8^i}$
            $$=\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{5^i-2(8^i)}{7^i\cdot7^{-2}+8^i}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{8^i}}{\frac{1}{8^i}}=\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} -2= -2 $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may write, as $i \to \infty$,
$$
a_i = \frac{5^i - 2^{3i+1}}{7^{i-2}+8^i}=\frac{2^{3i}}{8^i}\cdot\frac{(5/8)^i - 2}{\frac1{49}(7/8)^{i}+1}.
$$